# OpenSSH on Windows - "XXX Could not save your public key in __PROGRAMDATA__

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, openssh

I am trying to install OpenSSH on a Windows Server (2012 R2 standard) and I have been following the instructions at this locataion: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Windows_Server_2012&p=openssh

I ran Powershell as Administrator and all seems to install correctly up to the part where I try to generate the SSH host-key by running the command `.\ssh-keygen.exe -A` (step 7 of the instructions).
After running this it returns an error saying:

> RSA Could not save your public key in __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.9uX3wf3apv: No Such file of directory"

The same error also displays for DSA, ECDSA and ED25519.

[image: Screenshot of errors]

If anyone can tell me where I am going wrong here it would be appreciated. I've searched the web and not found any other references to this.

Answer (score 81):

The `__PROGRAMDATA__` refers to your environment variable `PROGRAMDATA` (Which probably is set to `C:\ProgramData`).

It is usually easiest to open an `cmd` command prompt and type

```
mkdir %PROGRAMDATA%\ssh
```

or powershell

```
mkdir $env:ProgramData\ssh
```

and then rerun the

```
.\ssh-keygen.exe -A
```

Comment: that did it for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Can anyone mark it?

Comment: @needfulthing The OP was last seen 2.5 years ago and only has reputation from this answer. It is unlikely an answer will ever be accepted.

Comment: I thought maybe some admin / forum operator can do this.

Answer (score 33):

I got the same error but when I manually added a folder under programdata called SSH and then ran the command again it seemed to work

Comment: This fixed my issue when I was trying it on Windows Server 2012R2, thanks! :)

Comment: Same fix required on Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this from an cmd prompt as powershell messes up the ProgramData variable.

Do this

> C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64>powershell .\install-sshd.ps1 -A

from a command prompt and you will probably be good to go.

Comment: "mkdir $env:ProgramData\ssh" in an Administrator Powershell worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can run it as administrator. This will give ssh-keygen.exe all the rights it needs to create files on its own.

```
runas.exe /noprofile /user:Administrator .\ssh-keygen.exe
```

This will install the keys under C:\Users\Administrator.ssh

If you want the keys to be accessible to your current user or another user just run Powershell as that user by right clicking on it and clicking `Run as Different User`.

**You do not want to be in an elevated Powershell when you generate keys**

OpenSSH runs from the current user and checks their C:\Users\UserName.ssh. Similar to how SSH works in Linux.